# &plusmn; (plus/minus character) converted to black question mark

Tags: php, html, ascii, special-characters

Some text I am entering includes several up and down arrows (↑ and ↓), as well as a plus/minus sign (±).

These special characters are entered as HTML ASCII: `&uarr;` `&darr;` `&plusmn;`.   On POST, the HTML is processed with htmlentities prior to being saved to the MySQL table.

```
$data   = htmlentities($data,ENT_QUOTES);
```

It is important to note that the up and down arrow symbols are not converted to black arrows.  After POSTing data, then going back to edit the same text - I see the `&uarr;` and `&darr;` in the HTML source code.  Only the `&plusmn;` is converted to the black question mark.

Checking the saved text in MySQL confirms that all three symbols are stored as follows (this after htmlentites is applied): `&amp;uarr;` `&amp;darr;` and `&amp;plusmn;`.

The PHP application then uses unhtmlentities($data) [below] to convert the entities back to symbols.  This works fine with `&uarr;` and `&darr;`.   Here is where I'm losing `&plusmn;`.

unhtmlentities:

```
function unhtmlentities ($string) {
    // Restores HTML code to inserted data
    // use when pulling from Database
    $trans_tbl = get_html_translation_table (HTML_ENTITIES);
    $trans_tbl = array_flip ($trans_tbl);
    return strtr ($string, $trans_tbl);
    // $c = unhtmlentities($a);
}
```

Why would this work fine for uarr and darr, but not with plusmn?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using `htmlentities` on data that's going into a database? This typically does nothing but cause problems. Store text as is, then use `htmlentities` on it before outputting it to a browser.

Comment: `html_entity_decode("&amp;plusmn;")` converts it back to the original HMTL charref. So does your function. Which is why this is probably more a font / dsiplay issue.

Comment: @sgroves - working with legacy code and 10g of data.  Trying to avoid cleaning up a huge mess by fixing a smaller problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still see `&plusmn;` in the source delivered to your browser, but a **`<?>`** is displayed, then it is likely your browser's fault. Check what your Character Encoding is set to.

edit: like mario commented, it could also simply be that that character does not exist in the font you are using.

Comment: I've isolated the issue to CKEditor.  Thanks.